# Make groups of a mesh and export it into COLLADA file

Tags: vertex-groups, collada

I'm trying to create groups inside an existing mesh. I want to have those groups exported in order to referenciate them and change its properties in the game engine (I'm using SceneKit right now).

I can create Vertex Groups in blender but when I export the file to COLLADA the vertex groups are not there so I cannot access them in SceneKit.

One alternative is to separate those vertex groups in different submeshes but that has some other impacts in blender, like for example, the UV mapping is different for each submesh.

Which is the right way to create and export vertex groups when using COLLADA?

Thanks